# Actualizar valores de Clase que tienen Bindig a TextBox en WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Que tal, me encontré con un problema, tengo unos `textbox` que tienen `binding`, pero me di cuenta que el valor en la clase no se actualiza hasta que doy clic en el `textbox`, quiero decir que me muestra el valor deseado pero si no doy clic en el `textbox` cuando mando a guardar esa propiedad me aparece como `Null`, como puedo solucionar esto? Ya que esos `textbox` los quiero ocultar,pero que aún así sigan teniendo los valores. Estoy utilizando `MVVM` y `WPF`

Gracias por su ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Pública la parte relevante del código para poder ayudarte

Comment: Tienes implementado INotifyPropertyChanged en tu clase?

Lo otro es que talvez necesites agregar, en el mismo binding la instrucción "Mode=TwoWay" y/o "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" que cambian la forma en que funciona el binding.

<TextBox Text="{Binding MiPropiedad, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"